# Determine valid values of two probabilities

Tags: random-variables

I have the random variable X that returns the result the thrown of one dice such that:
$P(1) = P(3) = P(4) = p_1, \\ P(5) = P(6) = p_2, \\ P(2) = \frac{1}{2}P(5)$
Determine the values of $p_1$ and $p_2$:

I have considered the definition of discrete random variable:
$$\sum_{\forall x} P(X=x) = 1 $$
therefore I have done:

$p_1 + \frac{1}{2}p_2 + p_1 + p_1 + p_2 + p_2 = 1 \\ 3p_1 + \frac{5}{2}p_2 = 1$

by attempts I have found that possible values can be:
$p_1 = \frac{1}{3} \land p_2=0$,
$p_1 = 0 \land p_2 = \frac{2}{5}$

Do exist other possible values?
Is there any algorithm to calculate that values without attempts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints that need to be satisfied are $$3p_1+ \frac{5}{2}p_2 =1 $$

and $$p_1 \geq 0$$ $$p_2 \geq 0$$

The constraint set is convex.

Hence any convex combination of two solution is a solution.

$$(p_1, p_2) = \lambda (\frac13, 0) + (1-\lambda) (0, \frac25)$$

where $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Remark: if you sketch out the feasible set, you will find that the feasible set is just a line segment where you have found the end points.

Comment: yes, but, what is the "list" of possible values?

Comment: $$(p_1, p_2) = \lambda (\frac13, 0) + (1-\lambda) (0, \frac25)$$ where $\lambda \in [0,1]$. These are all the possible values.

Comment: is it possible to do without convex combination?

Comment: This is a $2$-dimensional problem, you can sketch the feasible region.